# same image, different sizes: with picasso

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, picasso

I have an image that is to be displayed in about four different sizes depending on which activity the user is viewing. For instance a ListView will show one size, a GridView will show one size, a slide show will show one size, etc. If I use Picasso, will it download the image once or will it download one image for each size? Of course, I am taking into account that Picasso caches images (which is what I want). The key point here is that I have a single url for the image since it is one image.

Note that to keep the example simple, I mention one image. But of course I am talking about a set of images each of which needs to be manipulated as mentioned in the paragraph above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use Picasso, will it download the image once or will it download
>   one image for each size?

Once for the original size as you get from the URL.

You can use the `resize()` method to resize the image and the original image would still stay at full resolution. I have done that in my app where I displayed a 600x600 image at 150x150 in a thumbnail and in full resolution later.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using BitmapFun by Google and it does not do it like that. It's driving me crazy. So on your word, since you have done it, I will replace with Picasso and let you know how it turns out. There are so many libraries out there. I didn't want to go try out each one of them. So thanks for sharing your experience. +1

Comment: Picasso is so easy to use, my friend, it’s embarrassing! I just add the jar to my libs directory and from there it’s one line of code! **LITERALLY** one single line of code to load my images. To think I spent months — yes months — suffering through Google’s BitmapFun. I wish I could assassinate this post with up votes! And, oh, the resize method is a charm!!!